# Can anyone please explain why output of the following is such?

Tags: java

```
     String str1 = "abc:5";
     String str2 = "abc:" + str1.length();
     String str3 = "abc:" + 5;


     System.out.println(str1==str2);
     System.out.println(str1==str3);
```

Output of the program is :
false
true

But I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` operator will compare reference only

`.equals()` will compare the values.

in your case

`str1==str2` // compares the two references, which are different.

had it been, `str1.equals(str2)`, it would have compared the values, which will `return true`

**The “==” operator**

In Java, when the “==” operator is used to compare 2 objects, it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory. In other words, it checks to see if the 2 object names are basically references to the same memory location.The `“==”` operator compares the objects’ location(s) in memory

**The “equals” method**
The Java String class actually overrides the default `equals()` implementation in the `Object` class – and it overrides the method so that it checks only the values of the strings, not their locations in memory.

Comment: so here, str1 and str3 refers to same memory location??

Comment: @user2014 `"" + 5` here `5` is treated as String only, whereas `str.length()` will be considered as `int`, but hashcode of all the three are same. But not much sure as why the results are different, already upvoted for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here str1 = "abc:5"; is located in constant pool of string and str2 is concatenated with 2 different object with new operator. So both str1 and str2 are referring to different object. That's the reason it is showing false.

Comment: can u please explain the reason for str3 also....

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator is used for only reference variables in java. For example if you are comparing characters `a1` and `a2` you can use the `==` operator because the `char` type is highlighted in most IDEs in Java. To check if two Strings are equal to each other you can use `.equals()`or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` to compare the Strings. This is because Strings are objects, not primitives, and require their own method in the class to test if Strings are the same.

For the first `System.out.println();` statement, you would use `System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));` or `System.out.println(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2));`.

For the second `System.out.println();` statement, you would use `System.out.println(str1.equals(str3));` or `System.out.println(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str3));`.